# WCF Authentication Service

Tags: java, .net, wcf, authentication, single-sign-on

I am very new to WCF and I am trying to setup a SSO solution. We have a .net application and java application. We would like the users to login from the java app and authenticated via WCF Authentication service. I am following the example below to create the WCF server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515342.aspx

Once authenticated from the java applicaiton, would WCF service allow the users to go from the java application to .net application without re-authenticating? Is there something else I need to do from .net application?

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SSO, but here's some info on how to authenticate on WCF using username / password. It works wonders!

[MSDN WCF authentication with Username/Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131.aspx)